# UIPageViewController transition PageCurl with UIScrollView wrong page index

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have searched a lot before posting without success:

I have `UIPageViewController` with array of `UIViewController` and PageCurl as transition.

Every `UIViewController` consists of `UIScrollView` and `UIWebView`.

the scroll height calculated based on webview height after loading the content.

now when I load `UIPageViewController` and start navigation between `UIViewController` without scrolling the content every thing works fine. But if I scrolled any page and then navigate to the next page or previous one. it will redisplay the same page and then works again normally.

I have tested it on IOS7 and IOS8:

UIPageViewController viewDidLoad method:

```
    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:currentViewController];

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

self.pageController.doubleSided = NO;

[self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
[[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
[self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

View Controller webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
CGSize contentSize = aWebView.scrollView.contentSize;
webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 312, contentSize.width, contentSize.height);
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.f, contentSize.height+60);
```

***Edit***
 Here is the complete code for **viewControllerBeforeViewController** and **viewControllerAfterViewController** of UIPageViewController

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(NewsDetailVC *)viewController index];
    self.index = index;
    NSLog(@"view before %i", index);
    if (index <= 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    currentViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger index = [(NewsDetailVC *)viewController index];
    NSLog(@"view after %i", index);

    if (index >= self.newsList.count -1) {
        return nil;
    }
    index++;
    currentViewController =[self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

***Edit2***
The previous page is an UIViewController contains UITableView when click on a cell will pass the array of Items to UIPageViewController and the selected index.
The purpose of currentViewController because I have controls for font size, and current view background.
The UIPageViewController parent is UIViewController
Here is the code of viewControllerAtIndex:

```
- (NewsDetailVC *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    NewsDetailVC *childViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewsDetailVC"];
    childViewController.index = index;
    childViewController.selectedNews = [self.newsList objectAtIndex:index ];
    childViewController.selectedCategory = self.selectedCategory;
    return childViewController;
}
```

Comment: you should add the implementation of your `UIPageViewController` (especially `viewControllerAfterViewController` and `viewControllerBeforeViewController`)

Comment: Could you implement the delegate method pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers: with say putting in a log when it's called. Then try interacting with the ScrollView and see if that method gets called. Wondering if the gestures are causing confusion amongst the views

Comment: Where do you initially set index to 0?

Comment: And where are you calling `viewControllerAfterViewController:`? You need to add more code to your question.

Comment: index is passed from the previous UIViewController based on UITableView.in the edit above you can see both viewControllerBeforeViewController and viewControllerAfterViewController

Comment: @Ammar No, my question is how are viewControllerBeforeViewController and viewControllerAfterViewController *called*? And you really need to be more specific about how you're getting and setting `index` because it's probably the reason why your pages are redisplaying.

Comment: Please can you add some more code?  Specifically to clarify: 1) the `UIPageViewController viewDidLoad method` instantiates a new UIPageViewController - is the parent actually just a UIViewController? 2) how are the delegate/datasource set? 3) what's in the `viewControllerAtIndex:` method?  Does it create new VCs each time, or keep an array?  Also, where does `initialViewController` come from? 4) what purpose do `currentViewController` and `self.index` serve? 5) Can you confirm that you use gesture based navigation - or are you using a pageControl or similar to trigger the navigation? Thanks.

Comment: I've updated to post. initialViewController is now currentViewController, but I've changed the name later and forgot to update to original post.

Comment: Many thanks.  So if you are on (say) index 2 and you scroll, when you then navigate forward or back it reloads the page for index 2?  Does `viewControllerBefore...` or `viewControllerAfter...` get called when this happens (with index 2)?  Or does it reload without calling these methods?

Comment: If I didn't scroll the content, it will navigate to index 3 or index 1 normally, in both directions works correctly. But when scroll the content it reload same index(2) without calling these methods.

Comment: What is the purpose of self.index? Do you do anything with that? Because note that you are now setting it to pretty random values...

Comment: Note also that currentViewController is NOT the same one as returned from the ...Before... and ...After... methods. You create two separate instances. What's the reason you don't do `return currentViewController;` ?

Comment: currentViewController will be used later to change background and font size of current view, not finished yet, self.index not used yet too.

Comment: + 1 to @fishinear's comments. You still haven't provided nearly enough code OP. That index value is crucial, but you haven't let us know how you're getting it. And we still don't know how/when viewControllerBeforeViewController: and viewControllerAfterViewController: are being called.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with an UIPageViewController.

It seems like the index shown in *viewControllerAtIndex* is not quite an accurate one.

As somebody else mentioned in the comment above, in these situations you should implement the delegate method *pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers*.

In this method you should do your work:

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers {

    if ([pendingViewControllers count] > 0) {
        NSUInteger index = [(PageContentViewController *)
        [pendingViewControllers objectAtIndex:0] pageIndex];

    if (index == [yourArray count] - 1 || index == 0) {
      [self loadContent];
    } else {
      [self doOtherStuff];
    }
  }
}
```

Somehow, the * viewControllerAtIndex* is called several times, giving you troubles finding the index, but in this method the index should be accurate.

Hope it helps!